Who is my greatest nemesis?

I love scrabbles, and
I am not dsylexic.
I often hide my face, but...
I always go straight to the joint.
I do not have a jack, for
I have nothing to match with.
But, I do have an enemy!
He who acts like a pain.
That guy always flushes out me
at the puncture of me being high.
Too bad for them...
I always win in my game!
For I often appear at night.
And, we both love to all in.
So, who is that guy,
the one I call enemy?

My first "easy" original puzzle in this site.
(Giving another tag ruins the puzzle)
